# How can I find a hotel that can fill out a registration form for temporary visitors in China?

Tags: visas, china

How can I find a hotel that can fill out a registration form for temporary visitors in China?

I am in a small town not so far from Nanning at the moment. I have a double entry tourist visa with about ten days left. I am considering going to the PSB to extend the visa. I guess they will not extend anything without a "Registration form of temporary residence for visitors". I went around in the smaller hotels and asked if they could fill out a form. It seems like many small hotels won't do it. I found a business hotel that said they could do it, if I brought the form for them. So the question really is, can I use a black and white photocopied copy of the form printed from the Internet or do I need to find a hotel that has its own supply of this form that they can fill out? And is it enough if the hotel just fills it out so I can bring it to the PSB or do they have to do some registration work on a computer as well? I think the original copies are pink in color, my photocopy is black and white.

Here is a picture of the copy I have at the moment:

[http://i.imgur.com/1xPNU3u_d.webp?maxwidth=640&shape=thumb&fidelity=high](https://i.imgur.com/1xPNU3u_d.webp?maxwidth=640&shape=thumb&fidelity=high)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than looking for a hotel that might just complete a copy of the form, you need to actually find one licensed by the government such as these [international youth hostels in Nanning](http://www.echinacities.com/Nanning/city-guide/Nannings-International-Youth-Hostels) listed by eChinaCities.com. You then need to actually stay there on the night after application for visa extension.

According to what the [Beijing Municipal Public Security Bureau](http://www.ebeijing.gov.cn/visa/t1335648.htm), you must have the Registration Of Temporary Residence, the pink form you receive when you check in to a hotel or hostel that is licensed to host foreigners, and it needs to be for the night after you apply (not the night before).

Then, visit the Public Security Bureau (PSB) Exit and Entry Administration office for the municipality where you will be 'resident' on the night following the submission of the application. The PSB officers will issue you with a return receipt once they accepted your application and make the final decision within 7 days.

[Nomadasaurus Alesha and Jarryd](https://www.nomadasaurus.com/extending-your-chinese-visa-in-shanghai/) shared a detailed and useful description of how they successfully navigated the process in 2015.